# print jqgrid with borders and additional headings text above the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
  function printTable(){
            $("#active_grid").jqGrid("exportToHtml",{
                    includeLabels : true,
                    includeGroupHeader : true,
                    includeFooter: true,
                    autoPrint : true
                });
        }
```

I want print `jqgrid` table along with some text written above some headings, which is need to be appended at the time of printing, kindly help me. currently I am using this function.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you mean Guriddo jqGird. What you mean with "above some headings" - which heading and where?

There are [options for this purpose](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/exporting/#export-to-html) - topText, bottomText.

Always it is a good idea to read the docs, before to ask. You will save your and our time.

Comment: Sorry, I do not want waste anyone's time. I'll consider your suggestion. Thank you. "some headings" mean some title and two line description about whats in the table.